# How do I read a csv stored in S3 with csv.DictReader?

Tags: python, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have code that fetches an AWS S3 object.  How do I read this StreamingBody with Python's csv.DictReader?

```
import boto3, csv

session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=<>, aws_secret_access_key=<>, region_name=<>)
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
s3_object = s3_resource.Object(<bucket>, <key>)
streaming_body = s3_object.get()['Body']

#csv.DictReader(???)
```

Comment: `csv.DictReader(streaming_body)`?

Comment: `csv.DictReader(streaming_body)` returns the error "TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator".

Running read() and decode() on it before passing it (which I'd prefer to not do since that'll load the whole file in memory) returns each character from the file separately.

Answer (score 31):

The code would be something like this:

```
import boto3
import csv

# get a handle on s3
s3 = boto3.resource(u's3')

# get a handle on the bucket that holds your file
bucket = s3.Bucket(u'bucket-name')

# get a handle on the object you want (i.e. your file)
obj = bucket.Object(key=u'test.csv')

# get the object
response = obj.get()

# read the contents of the file and split it into a list of lines

# for python 2:
lines = response[u'Body'].read().split()

# for python 3 you need to decode the incoming bytes:
lines = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split()

# now iterate over those lines
for row in csv.DictReader(lines):

    # here you get a sequence of dicts
    # do whatever you want with each line here
    print(row)
```

You can compact this a bit in actual code, but I tried to keep it step-by-step to show the object hierarchy with boto3.

*Edit Per your comment about avoiding reading the entire file into memory*: I haven't run into that requirement so cant speak authoritatively, but I would try wrapping the stream so I could get a text file-like iterator. For example you could use the [codecs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#streamreader-objects) library to replace the csv parsing section above with something like:

```
for row in csv.DictReader(codecs.getreader('utf-8')(response[u'Body'])):
    print(row)
```

Comment: @Jon, did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Any way to do it so that I don't have to read() the entire file into memory?

Comment: The `codecs.getreader()` solution worked for me for this exact problem

Comment: The above code did not work for me as it is, but worked with a slight modification: `response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split()` . I am using Python 3.7

Comment: Is there anyway to keep file integrity without clean after the read?

Comment: for me, this required `.splitlines()` or `.split('\n')`