# issue in accessing specific columns of a csv file read as a S3 object with boto3

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, boto3

I am reading a `csv` file from `S3` using `boto3` and want to access specific columns of that `csv`. I have this code where I read the `csv` file into a `S3` object using `boto3` but I am having trouble in accessing specific columns out of it:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id = keyId, aws_secret_access_key = sKeyId)

obj = s3.Object(bucketName, srcFileName)

filedata = obj.get()["Body"].read()
print(filedata.decode('utf8'))

for row in filedata.decode('utf8'):
    print(row[1]) # Get the column at index 1
```

When I execute this above the `print(filedata.decode('utf8'))` prints following on my output console:

```
51350612,Gary Scott
10100063,Justin Smith
10100162,Annie Smith
10100175,Lisa Shaw
10100461,Ricardo Taylor
10100874,Ricky Boyd
10103593,Hyman Cordero
```

But the line `print(row[1])` inside `for` loop throws error as `IndexError: string index out of range`.

How can I remove this error and access specific columns out of a csv file from `S3` using `boto3?

Answer (score 2):

boto3.s3.get().read() will retrieve the whole file bytes object. Your code `filedata.decode('utf8')` only convert the whole bytes object into String object. There is no parsing happen here.  Here is a shameless copy from another answer [from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312196/how-do-i-read-a-csv-stored-in-s3-with-csv-dictreader).

```
import csv 
# ...... code snipped .... insert your boto3 code here

# Parse your file correctly 
lines = response[u'Body'].read().splitlines()
# now iterate over those lines
for row in csv.DictReader(lines):
    # here you get a sequence of dicts
    # do whatever you want with each line here
    print(row)
```

If you just have a simple CSV file, a quick and dirty fix will do

```
for row in filedata.decode('utf8').splitlines():
    items = row.split(',')
    print(items[0]. items[1])
```

[How do I read a csv stored in S3 with csv.DictReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312196/how-do-i-read-a-csv-stored-in-s3-with-csv-dictreader)

Answer (score 0):

To read from the CSV properly, import the CSV python module and use one of its readers.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: I know how to read a csv file. The issue is reading a csv file from amazon s3 using `boto3` package and then accessing a specific column out of it which is throwing error