# AWS lambda function to write csv data to an Amazon DynamoDB table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Below is the code to trigger a lambda function when a csv file is uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket and write data to an Amazon DynamoDB table. I am getting error "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict".

Could you please suggest where is the mistake I did.

````
import boto3
import csv

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
#table = dynamodb.Table('batch_data')

def csv_write(table_name, rows):
    table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

    with table.csv_write() as batch:
        for row in rows:
            batch.put_item(Item=row)
    return True

def read_csv(csv_file, list):
    rows = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file))

    for row in rows:
        list.append(row)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:

        bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        csv_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
        response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key= csv_file_name)

        table_name = 'batch_data'
        items = []

        read_csv(response, items)
        status = csv_write(table_name, items)

        if(status):
            print('Data saved')
        else:
            print('Error in saving data...')
    except Exception as err:
        print (err)
    ```
````

Comment: Where exactly the error orginates from?

Comment: i think you are following a youtube tutorial, mka sure to check your data types of csv file

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key= csv_file_name)
```

returns an object like this:

```json
{
    'Body': StreamingBody(),
    'LastModified': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    'ContentLength': 123,
    ...
}
```

This line:

```
read_csv(response, items)
```

is passing that `response` to this function as `csv_file`:

```py
def read_csv(csv_file, list):
    rows = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file))
    ...
```

However, the `open()` command doesn't know how to interpret the response object from S3. That is why it is returning the error:

> expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict

Based on information from [How do I read a csv stored in S3 with csv.DictReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42329747/174777), I got this code working:

```py
import boto3
import csv

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    csv_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key= csv_file_name)

    lines = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split()
    for row in csv.DictReader(lines):
        print(row)
```

You can use that method to read the CSV from the `StreamingBody` that is returned from `get_object()`.

Answer (score 0):

likely your bucket or csv_file_name is inadvertently a dictionary, i.e. you didn't exhaust the hierarchy of event